# How to use Mockito for testing sendEmail() method without sending email?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I need your help with using Mockito for unit tests.
My project have only DAOs and Services, so it's web project. 
I have interface `EmailDao` and it's implementation `EmailDaoImpl` class. Now I have simple jUnit test for testing methods in `EmailDaoImpl`. This is method `sendEmail(EmailParams params)` that performs operations such as authentication correctly set parameters in the object `EmailParams`, calling other methods to save a copy of email to the file system, etc.. and, of course, send email.

My actual test class looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManagerTest")
public class EmailServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmailDao emailDao;

    @Test
    //@Rollback(false)
    public void sendSignedEmailTest() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    System.out.println("sendSignedEmail()");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");      

    String body = "Hello, I'm evil!";

    EmailParams params = new EmailParams();
    params.setIsCourt(true);
    params.setBody(body);
    params.setFileName("test.eml");        
    params.setSaveToFile(false);
    params.setSignMessage(false);
    params.setFromAddress("xxxx@seznam.cz");
    params.setToAddresses("yyyyy@gmail.com");
    //params.setMailPriority(5);
    //params.setCcs("zzzzz@seznam.cz");
    params.setSubject("test");
    params.setUserName("aaa");

    List<Long> debtIds = new ArrayList<>();
    debtIds.add(123018L);
    //debtIds.add(184788L);
    //debtIds.add(185864L);
    params.setDebtIds(debtIds);

    DebtEvent event = new DebtEvent();
    event.setEventTypeId(5);
    event.setStatusTypeId(50);
    event.setDescription("description");
    event.setEventText("event text");
    event.setEventClientText("event client text");

    params.setSaveDebtEvent(false);
    params.setDebtEventTemplate(event);

    boolean ff = emailDao.sendEmail(params);

    System.out.println(ff);

}
```

Now I don't want to really send email to target address. So, I take Mockito:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "txManagerTest")
public class EmailServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private EmailDao emailDao;

    @Test
    //@Rollback(false)
    public void sendSignedEmailTest() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    System.out.println("sendSignedEmail()");
    System.out.println("-------------------------");      

    String body = "Hello, I'm evil!";

    EmailParams params = new EmailParams();
    params.setIsCourt(true);
    params.setBody(body);
    params.setFileName("test.eml");        
    params.setSaveToFile(false);
    params.setSignMessage(false);
    params.setFromAddress("xxxx@seznam.cz");
    params.setToAddresses("yyyyy@gmail.com");
    //params.setMailPriority(5);
    //params.setCcs("zzzzz@seznam.cz");
    params.setSubject("test");
    params.setUserName("aaa");

    List<Long> debtIds = new ArrayList<>();
    debtIds.add(123018L);
    //debtIds.add(184788L);
    //debtIds.add(185864L);
    params.setDebtIds(debtIds);

    DebtEvent event = new DebtEvent();
    event.setEventTypeId(5);
    event.setStatusTypeId(50);
    event.setDescription("description");
    event.setEventText("event text");
    event.setEventClientText("event client text");

    params.setSaveDebtEvent(false);
    params.setDebtEventTemplate(event);

    Mockito.when(emailDao.sendEmail(params)).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);

    System.out.println(emailDao.sendEmail(params));

}
```

This code always return true (it's ok), but the method sendEmail is not tested!

Can u help me with this problem please? I don't know what else i must to do :-(

Thanks!

**EDIT://**
This is sendEmail(EmailParams params) in EmailDaoImpl class:

```
@Override
    public boolean sendEmail(EmailParams params) throws MessagingException, EmailException {

        String from = params.getFromAddress(); 
        String to = params.getToAddresses(); 
        String ccs = params.getCcs();
        String bccs = params.getBccs();
        String subject = params.getSubject(); 
        String body = params.getBody();        
        boolean signMessage = params.isSignMessage();
        boolean saveToFile = params.isSaveToFile();
        String fileName = params.getFileName();
        boolean isCourt = params.isIsCourt();
        List<Long> debtIds = params.getDebtIds();
        String userName = params.getUserName();
        String priority = (params.getMailPriority() == null || params.getMailPriority() == 0) ? "3" : params.getMailPriority().toString();

        String message;

        // remove any last semicolon
        if (StringUtils.hasText(to)) {
            if (to.endsWith(";")) {to = to.substring(0, to.length()-1);}
            if (to.startsWith(";")) {to = to.substring(1, to.length());}            
        }

        if (StringUtils.hasText(bccs)) {
            if (bccs.endsWith(";")) {bccs = bccs.substring(0, bccs.length()-1);}
            if (bccs.startsWith(";")) {bccs = bccs.substring(1, bccs.length());}        
        }

        if (StringUtils.hasText(ccs)) {
            if (ccs.endsWith(";")) {ccs = ccs.substring(0, ccs.length()-1);}
            if (ccs.startsWith(";")) {ccs = ccs.substring(1, ccs.length());}        
        }        

        // addresses checking
        if (StringUtils.hasText(to)) {
            to = this.checkEmailAddress(to);
        }
        else {
            message = messageSource.getMessage("email.NoRecipientAddress.message", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());            
            throw new EmailException(message);                                    
        }

        if (StringUtils.hasText(bccs)) {
            bccs = this.checkEmailAddress(bccs);
        }

        if (StringUtils.hasText(ccs)) {
            ccs = this.checkEmailAddress(ccs);
        }        

        // unless priority is set correctly, the end
        if (!priority.matches("[135]")) {
            message = messageSource.getMessage("email.InvalidPriorityType.message", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());            
            throw new EmailException(message);            
        }        

        byte[] bytes = null;

        // I get a template events
        DebtEvent debtEventTemplate = params.getDebtEventTemplate();

        // if to store the event
        if (params.isSaveDebtEvent()) {

            // If the template is not defined, then the end
            if (debtEventTemplate == null) {
                message = messageSource.getMessage("email.InvalidDebtEventTemplate.message", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());            
                throw new EmailException(message);            
            }

            // if the event does not have date, complementing the current date
            if (debtEventTemplate.getEventDate() == null) debtEventTemplate.setEventDate(Calendar.getInstance());

            // specify type of storage
            debtEventTemplate.setRepositoryId((isCourt) ? 2 : 1);     

        }        

        // create a collection of the SMTP server settings
        Properties props = System.getProperties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", mailPort);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", mailProtocol);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", mailAuth);        
        props.put("mail.smtps.debug", mailDebug);

        // create email session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        // based on session I create the unsigned MimeMessage and configure it
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        mimeMessage.setText(body);
        mimeMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));        
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, this.stringToEmailAddresses(to));
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, this.stringToEmailAddresses(ccs));
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, this.stringToEmailAddresses(bccs));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);        
        mimeMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
        mimeMessage.setHeader("X-Priority", priority);
        mimeMessage.saveChanges();

        // setup priority
        switch (priority) {

            case "1":
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-Priority", priority);
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-MSMail-Priority", "High");
                mimeMessage.setHeader("Importance", "High");
                break;

            case "3":
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-Priority", priority);
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-MSMail-Priority", "Normal");
                mimeMessage.setHeader("Importance", "Normal");
                break;

            case "5":
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-Priority", priority);
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-MSMail-Priority", "Low");
                mimeMessage.setHeader("Importance", "Low");
                break; 

            default:
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-Priority", priority);
                mimeMessage.setHeader("X-MSMail-Priority", "Normal");
                mimeMessage.setHeader("Importance", "Normal");
                break;                

        }

        // If the email sign
        if (signMessage) {

            // create and configure MailcapCommandMap and MIME types used for SMIME
            final MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
            mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_signature");
            mailcap.addMailcap("application/pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.pkcs7_mime");
            mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-signature;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_signature");
            mailcap.addMailcap("application/x-pkcs7-mime;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.x_pkcs7_mime");
            mailcap.addMailcap("multipart/signed;; x-java-content-handler=org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.handlers.multipart_signed");

            CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mailcap);            

            // sign message
            MimeMultipart mm = null;

            try {
                mm = signMessage(mimeMessage);
            } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (CertificateException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (CertStoreException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (SMIMEException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(EmailDaoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            // Copied headers from the original unsigned messages to new message
            final Enumeration headers = mimeMessage.getAllHeaderLines();

            // create a new envelope
            mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);

            while (headers.hasMoreElements()){
                mimeMessage.addHeaderLine((String)headers.nextElement());
            }

            // I put the signed content
            mimeMessage.setContent(mm);
            mimeMessage.saveChanges();

        }     

        // If email have to save to file
        if (saveToFile) {

            // too many lines of code 

        }              

        // send email
        Transport.send(mimeMessage);        

        // return true
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Why do you mock `EmailDao` if you want to test it? Mocks are used for collaborators that the unit your are testing needs to be present since it callss methods on them. What is the unit you test? What are the collaborators?

Comment: What do you want to test? If you want to test the DAO, you should mock its dependencies, not the DAO itself. SHow us the body of the method, and explain what you want your test to verify.

Comment: I added code of sendEmail method

Answer (score 1):

The `emailDao` with `sendEmail` method should be tested in a separate test (test of dao).

In that test you should mock emailService (the part responsible only for communication with web server).

You shouldn't test all the stuff in the same test class, since it would be too complicated.

If you want to check what parameters were passed to `sendEmail` method you can use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn`. Read more about `answers` in Mockito.

Comment: Better way to check answers is to use an `ArgumentCaptor`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have no asserts.  If you don't assert, you don't test.
Second, since your DAO is doing both the saving and the mailing, that means it's not actually a DAO.  Call it a service or something.

As for your question, you're getting true because you're asking mockito to do so.

When you test a unit, that means you give it fixed input, expect a specific output, and mock all dependencies.  You do not mock the class that you test.

The mail sending itself should be handled by another component; that is the one you should mock.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to test a class (and it's methods) you should not mock it ! In fact a mock is a dummy implementation of an interface or a class. It is used normally to mock calls to methods of other classes (and don't worry about dependencies, and concentrate on tested class).

Best regards